# pyomo accuracy; objective rule doesn´t return the expacted value

Tags: python, pyomo, objective-function

using pyomo and glpk solver I defind the follwing ojective rule:

```
def cost_rule(m): 
    return (sum(m.rd[i]*m.pRdImp*m.dt - m.vr[i]*m.pRdExp*m.dt for i in m.t) + m.cb + m.cPV + (150+10*m.kWp) )
m.cost = Objective(rule=cost_rule)
```

If I know compare the outputs after a minimum was found I get different results:

```
sum(m.rd[i]()*m.pRdImp()*m.dt() - m.vr[i]()*m.pRdExp()*m.dt() for i in t_t) + m.cPV() + m.cb() + (150+5*m.kWp())
Out[46]: 1136.468

m.cost()
Out[43]: 1173.178
```

(m.t and t_t are range sets representing the hours of a year)
This is an error of around 3 %, any ideas where is could come from? And which value would be the correct one if I would need to choose one.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expressions are different. The last term in the first one is `(150+10*m.kWp)` and the last term in the second one is `(150+5*m.kWp())`

Comment: thanks a lot , what a shame didn´t saw this in hours